# Deleted a partition by mistake

Tags: boot-partition

I just deleted a partition by mistake. And now I don't know if I shutdown I will get things back.

`lsblk` looks like this, I can't find any `boot` mount point.

```
root@Dell-Precision-T1600:/home/hell# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1    7:1    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2344
loop2    7:2    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
loop3    7:3    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/547
loop4    7:4    0  44.7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/15534
loop5    7:5    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2409
loop6    7:6    0 187.7M  1 loop /snap/deja-dup/520
loop7    7:7    0  65.2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
loop8    7:8    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1405
loop9    7:9    0 248.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
loop10   7:10   0 247.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87
loop11   7:11   0   193M  1 loop /snap/deja-dup/525
loop12   7:12   0  81.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop13   7:13   0  43.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/15177
loop14   7:14   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop15   7:15   0  54.2M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/558
loop16   7:16   0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1434
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   931G  0 part /
```

And the `fdisk -l` looks like this.

```
root@Dell-Precision-T1600:/home/hell# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 55.53 MiB, 58212352 bytes, 113696 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 50.98 MiB, 53432320 bytes, 104360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 44.69 MiB, 46845952 bytes, 91496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 55.55 MiB, 58232832 bytes, 113736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 187.74 MiB, 196837376 bytes, 384448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 65.22 MiB, 68378624 bytes, 133552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: CT1000MX500SSD1 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0cdc526e

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          2048    1050623    1048576  512M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2       1052670 1953523711 1952471042  931G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672 1953523711 1952471040  931G 83 Linux

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/loop8: 61.92 MiB, 64901120 bytes, 126760 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 248.78 MiB, 260841472 bytes, 509456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 247.93 MiB, 259948544 bytes, 507712 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 193 MiB, 202379264 bytes, 395272 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 81.27 MiB, 85209088 bytes, 166424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 43.64 MiB, 45748224 bytes, 89352 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop15: 54.24 MiB, 56872960 bytes, 111080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop16: 61.92 MiB, 64909312 bytes, 126776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
root@Dell-Precision-T1600:/home/hell#
```

i can't find any boot partition. How do I restore it? Also, there is a message `Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.`

Comment: Try with testdisk

Comment: And please add `cat /etc/fstab` to your question.

Comment: surprisingly, Just reinstalled the grub2. And still `/boot/efi` is empty and the reboot is completely fine.